# SQL query to combine two tables while also showing all records from one table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm running the below query to try and get all the categories in my forum, with their latest topics posted. There are some categories that have no topics posted yet and want to return those also.

```
SELECT cat_id,cat_name,cat_description, Null as topic_date, 
       Null as topic_subject 
FROM categories 
UNION ALL 
SELECT cat_id, cat_name, cat_description, topic_date, topic_subject 
FROM categories, topics t  
WHERE t.topic_cat=cat_id  AND topic_id IN
  (SELECT topic_id FROM 
    (SELECT topic_id FROM 
      (SELECT topic_id, topic_subject, MAX(topic_date) AS 'recent'
       FROM topics  
       GROUP BY topic_Cat 
       ) a
    ) b
  );
```

This query returns the following results:-

```
+--------+-----------+---------+------------+---------------+
| cat_id | cat_name  | cat_des | topic_date | topic_subject |
+--------+-----------+---------+------------+---------------+
|      1 |  T20 World|  Posts1 | NULL                | NULL |
|      2 |  Test     |  delete1| NULL                | NULL |
|      3 |  Test 2   |  txt    | NULL                | NULL |
|      1 |  T20 World|  Posts1 | 2016-04-01 01:54:01 | test |
|      2 |  Test     |  delete1| 2016-04-01 03:05:58 | test |
+--------+---------------+------------------------+--------+
```

As you can see, cat_id 3 has no posts yet and is returned as desired!, however cat_id 1&2, is repeated.

I'm trying to remove the duplications and I'm not sure what I'm missing

Comment: I'm pretty sure you just need a `left join`.  But without sample data and a description of what you are doing, it is hard to formulate a real answer.

Comment: I think I could've rewritten the query with a left join. New to sql. Will definitely try this next time. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a left outer join clause to join the results of topics to those of categories *only if they exist*. Somewhere along these lines:

```
SELECT c.cat_id, c.cat_name, c.cat_description, 
       max(t.topic_date), t.topic_subject
FROM categories c LEFT OUTER JOIN topics t ON t.topic_cat=c.cat_id
GROUP BY c.cat_id, c.cat_name, c.cat_description, t.topic_subject;
```

Comment: Thank you for the feed back, this came close to answering my question. Got rid of the NULL values but the rows that had multiple posts were stil returned.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `UNION ALL` with `UNION`. The latter removes duplicates.

However, by your code you're probably trying to do a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, so you should check some tutorials on `OUTER JOIN`s

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The union all didnt change the results since the other results were not exactly duplicates

Answer (score 0):

A bit rusty on `SQL` but something like this should work:

```
SELECT
  cat.cat_id, cat.cat_name, cat.cat_desc, topic.topic_date, topic.topic_subject
FROM
  categories AS cat
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT
    topics.topic_date, topics.topic_subject
  FROM
    topics
  ORDER BY
    topics.topic_date DESC
  LIMIT
    1
  )
  AS topic ON topic.cat_id = cat.cat_id;
```

Comment: Thank you for the feed back

Answer (score 0):

What eventually worked for me was taking the results of the of union as a derived table into another select statement that grouped the results by cat_id, which resulted in removing duplicates and null values.

I also swapped the two select statements in the UNION around, so the filtered one was done first, followed by the one that displayed all rows.

Thank you for the feedback!

SELECT * FROM (SELECT  * FROM ( SELECT cat_id, cat_name, cat_description, topic_id, topic_subject, MAX(topic_date)
AS 'topic_date' from categories, topics WHERE topic_cat=cat_id GROUP BY topic_Cat)a UNION SELECT cat_id,cat_name,cat_description, 
NULL as topic_id, Null as topic_date, Null as topic_subject FROM categories)b GROUP BY cat_name ;